# Can (or should) we use the same file for different android projects?

Tags: java, android

Say I implement an algorithm for a project. Say I want the same code to be used on another project. What would be the approach to do so? Just copy and paste code? Create a "library" project? What? Is there a tutorial or site that explains how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a class/set of classes generic enough to be reutilizable, the solution would be separating them to a different project.

In your IDE, make your projects use the generic project as part of their build path (it is more flexible than including a jar).

When deploying, package all the generic classes in a jar and it to your solution. Don't forget to include that jar in the classpath.

In Java, there is no difference between "main project" and "library", other than the "library" usually does not include any `main` method (but it is not forbidden). They are classes in the classpath.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, add it to a library project, but the benefit of reuse should always be compared to the cost of making the code general. Sure if you improve the code by fixing a bug or increasing performance, it is nice to get that into all projects where you use the code, but it also makes you slower because you have to keep the library compatible with all clients (at least the ones that will build after a breaking change).

It is often better to copy and adapt solutions to new projects, than to maintain far more complex solutions. One very important thing to take into account is how many client you think you will have for the library. How much work would it be to maintain those clients separately?

On the other hand some code is generic by nature and can most definitely be shared in a library to make your life easier.

Answer (score 2):

If your algorithm is in Java, build it as a jar.

Then create a folder called "libs" in the root directory of your android project. Copy your jar into that folder. In eclipse go to
     -> Properties -> Java Build Path
Under tab "Libraries", add your jar.

Now you can use your code.

You can as well link it with multiple projects.

If your algorithm is in natice C/C++, follow
http://marakana.com/s/introduction_to_ndk,1153/index.html

Comment: I sort of like to debug the code in the library. So I want the to treat the library like any other code.